# Maintain an empty directory structure in git that ignores any files in them

Tags: git

I have a directory structure that a third party library requires to have as a workspace, so I want to have that file structure present in my repo.  However, if there are any temporary files in those directories, i never want to actually commit them.

so, for example, I might have:

```
/data
|----/dir1
|----/dir2
     |----/dir3
```

and the existence of those directories is required for the program to run successfully, but I would not want to accidentally commit a 5GB temporary data file or something like that.

So, what I did was add a `.gitignore` at the root of the `/data` directory with the following contents:

```
*
!*.gitignore
!*.keep
```

The idea being that it will ignore everything in both the current and all child directories, except for any file ending in `.gitignore` and `.keep`

I then add a `.keep` to each of my directories:

```
/data
.gitignore
|----/dir1
     .keep
|----/dir2
     .keep
     |----/dir3
          .keep
```

I then run `git add --all` for good measure, and run `git commit`

result:

```
new file:   data/.gitignore
```

but all of the `.keep` files were ignored.  What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adding your patterns to the `.gitignore` file at the root of your project directory structure and then going around adding `.keep` files under each sub-dir to get Git to add the directory structure itself, I'd recommend adding a separate `.gitignore` file inside each sub-directory rather than the project root.

Your `.gitignore` file would look at follows:

```
# ignore everything in the current dir
*

# except this file
!.gitignore
```

You'd use these carefully and in the specific (sub)directories where you want to ignore all content without having to mess around with additional extensions. Note that you can still keep your `.gitignore` file at the project's root with its own set of patterns. Just watch out for potential conflicts.

Your structure would look as follows:

```
/data
|----/dir1
     .gitignore
|----/dir2
     .gitignore
     |----/dir3
          .gitignore
```

#### Workaround: `git add -f <filename>`

As noted, if all the `.gitignore` files have the `*` wild card and are set to ignore everything, Git will apply these settings to child directories. In the example above, the `dir3/.gitignore` file would never be processed by `git add` due to the wild card in `dir2/.gitignore`.

One possibility to work around this is to **force** Git to add the `.gitignore` files in the sub-directories.

In the example above, you can use `git add -f dir2/dir3/.gitignore` to force Git to add the file. This will allow you to get the directory structure you want, while at the time time avoiding future content from being tracked in those directories.

Comment: This will exclude child directories, so those need to be added to the exception list within each .gitignore file.

Comment: @siride: That's why I left a warning to "watch out for potential conflicts" and to "use these carefully" :)

Comment: won't the `*` in the `.gitignore` cause it to exclude all of the `.gitignore` files in all of the child directories as well? note that i already have `*` in my current version of this.

Comment: @JHixson: Yes, unfortunately it does, though you should be able to specify specific patterns within each `.gitignore` file in each sub-dir instead of saying ignore everything with `*`. Also, your current version is at the project's *root* directory; I was recommending going to each sub-dir instead. Alternatively, you could write a script (Perl, Python, Shell, or ...) that creates the directory structure, along with the `.gitignore` files automatically, similar to what @Schwern mentioned

Comment: @JHixson: Please see updated post. I think it's a workable solution for you.

Comment: @ray Hey, sorry to come back to this after so long, but I just want to clarify something before I mark this as an answer for posterity's sake: since we are having to forcibly add the `.gitignore` files anyway, there isn't any point in them actually containing anything, correct? I mean, they are not doing anything that the root `.gitignore` hasn't already done.  and since they could just be empty files, is there any reason to call them `.gitignore` at all?  Can't I just call them `.keep` so that their purpose is a little bit more clear?

Comment: @JHixson: You're right AFAIK, the files wouldn't really need to contain any patterns if the root `.gitignore` file has them. The only reasons I'd have to still use `.gitignore` are: 1) if you do need to add patterns in the future for a sub-dir only, then you wouldn't need to rename `.keep` to `.gitignore` for Git to start paying attention to the patterns; and 2) Git naming convention: others would know where to add any future patterns if they're needed.

Answer (score 3):

You're running afoul of this (from [gitignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)).

> It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded. Git doesn't list excluded directories for performance reasons, so any patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter where they are defined.

I don't know how to work around it in Git.

However, this indicates your program is quite fragile. Your program should be robust enough to create those directories itself. Alternatively, your build system should create them.